# Unable to create Tables using SQL alchemy and fastAPI

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am learning how to use fastapi and sql alchemy to build an api, but when trying to get my script to create the tables in postgreSQL it just doesn't work, nothing happens.

This is what my code looks like:

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    DB_URL: str =  f'postgresql+asyncpg://{db_user}:{db_password}@{host}:{db_port}/{db_name}'
    DBbaseModel = declarative_base()

    class Config:
        case_sensitive = True


settings = Settings()
```

this is my engine and session:

```
engine : AsyncEngine = create_async_engine(settings.DB_URL)

Session: AsyncSession =  sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession, bind=engine
)
```

and this is what my script to create the tables looks like:

```
async def create_tables() -> None:
    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(settings.DBbaseModel.metadata.drop_all)
        await connection.run_sync(settings.DBbaseModel.metadata.create_all)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(create_tables())
```

I did that following a step by step tutorial even, and yet it doesn't work. can anyone please help me with this?

Edit:
as requested this is one of my models:

```
from core.configs import Settings
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

class UserModel(Settings.DBbaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    fullname: Column(String)
    email: Column(String)
    password: Column(String)
```

Comment: Could you add a little example showing one of the models you are trying to create? Maybe it'd help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `asyncpg` to connect to your PostgreSQL database, but you are using `run_sync` to execute your database commands.

`run_sync` is intended for use with synchronous functions, but you are using it with async functions. Instead, you should use `connection.run` to execute your async functions.

Edit your code like this:

```
async def create_tables() -> None:
async with engine.begin() as connection:
    await connection.run(settings.DBbaseModel.metadata.drop_all)
    await connection.run(settings.DBbaseModel.metadata.create_all)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(create_tables())
```

Comment: I tried doing this but I run isn't a valid method for my connection object. I don't know if it is because I started my engine as an AsyncEngine, but it returns the following error: `AttributeError: 'AsyncConnection' object has no attribute 'run'`

should I change the type of connection of my engine?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

The issue was that I had to add a line with `__allow_unmapped__ = True` in my models  for it to work